# Mail GAE not sending but

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have a problem sending mail with JavaMail Service in GAE.
I did all the code in the documentation, i debug it online and it work fine, and it count the mail sended in the quota section the problem is, i didn't receive anything, and also checked with the account sender and it's the same there isn't any trace of mail sended. I tried this for some mails address and it's not working too.
Anyone had this problem yet? A solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the mail sended as SPAM on gmail account.
Read doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Authenticating_mail_DKIM

Answer (score 0):

The email used to send the mails must be a member of the application. It can be the problem... It was with me.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/
The link is about python but for sure that the same email rules apply to Java.

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of the >following:
>
> The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
>   Any email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com or >anything@appalias.appspotmail.com
>   Any email address listed in Email API Authorized Senders found in the App >Engine Settings page of the Developers Console